# Regarding string replacement in python

Tags: python

I have a file `lid_details.txt` like this:

```
sdlfksdflsdsdf          -       10.3.2.142

qweioqwieuew            -       10.123.23.12

98327499a87             -       10.3.2.142

sdflkuw39834tn          -       10.3.2.142

kfpe84of9               -       10.3.2.142

dfgiueorgkdk            -       10.3.2.142
```

in which I want to replace the ipaddress with the new ipaddress specified by the user.

```
def modifyEntry(self, new_ip):

                fileref = open ("lid_details.txt","a+")
                for line in fileref:
                        match = re.search(r'(\w+)\s+-\s+(.*)', line)
                        if ( (match.group(1).strip()) == self.id):
                                print (match.group(2))
                                print new_ip
                                line = line.replace(match.group(2).strip() , new_ip)
                                print line
```

I'm importing this file into another file.Consider this is the respective module that I'm calling from another file where `new_ip` is the new ipaddress that I want to replace.

I'm able to see the address being reflected back when print line statement is executed.
But when I open the file `lid_details.txt`, I find that still that old ip remains same.

Please let me know the solution for this and also the reason.

Comment: you need to write the updated line to the file

Comment: Also, you could rewrite `if ( (match.group(1).strip()) == self.id):` more Pythonically as: `if match.group(1) == self.id:`. You don't need all those extra parenthesis, and the `strip()` is superfluous because you've already precluded terminating whitespace in your regexp. The `match.group(2).strip()` later is still required, specifically because your group 2 capture is `(.*)`, which might include whitespace. Make it `(\S*)` and you won't need the second `strip()` either.

Answer (score 0):

The string that you are modifying are the in memory ones.
You have to write in the file the modified line in order to get it effectively modified.

Answer (score 0):

Add all lines to a list with `fileref.readlines()`, use `enumerate` to keep track of the index of each line, then write the updated data to the file, if you want to replace the data you do not want to use `a` as this will append to the file not overwrite the old values

```
def modifyEntry(self, new_ip):
    with  open ("lid_details.txt","r") as fileref:
        lines = fileref.readlines()
        for ind,line in enumerate(lines):
            match = re.search(r'(\w+)\s+-\s+(.*)', line)
            if match: # check if we have a match first
                if match.group(1).strip() == self.id:
                    lines[ind]= line.replace(match.group(2) ,new_ip) # replace updated line in lines
        with open("lid_details.txt","w") as f: # open in `w` mode and write updated values
            for line in lines:
                fileref.write(line)
```

You should also use `if match` first as the lines with no matching ip will cause an error when you check  `if match.group(1)`.

Using:

```
line = line.replace(match.group(2).strip() , new_ip)
```

just creates a new variable line whose value is the updated line string, without writing to the file it does not change the file contents.

If you file is as above you don't need re:

```
def modifyEntry( new_ip):
    with open ("lid_details.txt","r+") as fileref:
        lines = fileref.readlines()
        for ind,line in enumerate(lines):
            spl = line.rsplit(" ",1)
            if spl[-1].rstrip() == self.id:
                        lines[ind] = line.replace(spl[1] ,new_ip+"\n")
        with open("lid_details.txt","w") as f:
            for line in lines:
                fileref.write(line)
```

If you just wanted the ip from the line with re you could use:

```
match = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', line)
```

Using findall:

```
def modifyEntry( new_ip):
    with open ("lid_details.txt","r+") as fileref:
        lines = fileref.readlines()
        for ind,line in enumerate(lines):
            match = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', line) # match 10.0.0.1 etc..
            if match:
                if match[0] == self.id:
                    lines[ind] = line.replace(match[0] ,new_ip+"\n")
        with open("lid_details.txt","w") as f:
            for line in lines:
                f.write(line)
```

You should also use `with` to open your files, it closes them automatically for you or at least close your file when you are done.

Comment: Saw the edit to this, it seems a little unnecesary, and imo would look much nice using a `with ... as ... :` block for the file.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried ur first suggestion. it's working fine. But even I have tried it slightly in a different way. Its' not working. Could u tell me whats the difference please.                              if match.group(1).strip() == self.id:
                    lines[ind]= line.replace(match.group(2) ,new_ip)                   for line in lines: fileref.write(line). This is not working. Both the codes are same right?

Comment: if there is no match there will be no group so you will get an error, if you don't overwrite the file contents then you will not overwrite the line, using `fileref.write(line)` does not overwrite that line. The best way is to just reopen the file as I have and overwrite the updated lines,

Comment: Thanks for your help. In future this helps me when handling files. :)